# Move segments of an sphere apart from each other

Tags: transforms

[image]I have a sphere of hexagons, made from an Icosphere and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> (whatever that short cut is?), which I then split each selected hexagon apart from the original object (resulting in 33 of them).

I want to move the hexagons away from the center so they get some space/gap between them, not scaling as this just make the whole thing bigger. I need to move each hexagon in the direction that they are facing or from center point of the old Icosphere.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all of your objects in object mode and choose Object -> Transform -> Origin to Geometry.

Then the origins will move to the center of each piece.

Then in the bottom header, to the right of the Object Mode drop down, is a button with a double-headed arrow beneath three dots. Turning this one will "Move Object Origins only..." Then, when you scale it will only scale their POSITION, not their SIZE.

Don't forget to turn it back off.

Comment: Picture added. ALT S doesn't do activate anything for me? Object mode? Or do I have to do this in each objects mesh edit mode? ALT S doesn't seem to work there either.

Comment: Sorry, in edit mode. But now that I see the picture, your situation is different. I'll change the answer.